# How to add methods to managed attributes in Python Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-decorators, method-chaining

Currently I have a python class function where

```
class Data:
    
    def __init__(self, data=None, target=None):

        self._data = None
        self._target = None

        self.X = data
        self.y = target

    @property
    def X(self):
        return self._data
    
    @X.setter
    def X(self, data):
        self._data = data
    
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._target
    
    @y.setter
    def y(self, target):
        self._target = target

    def view(self, method):

        print(pd.DataFrame(method))
```

What I want to be able to do is to add a view method to existing managed attributes and the view method will print the attribute to which it was added to.

```
d = Data([1,2,3], [4, 5, 6])
d.X.view()
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3

d.y.view()
    0
0   4
1   5
2   6
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You already can do this, if `_data` has a `view` method.

Comment: I understand that but I am not sure how to add a `view` method to `_data` and `_target`.

Comment: What *are* `_data` and `_target`? *Your* class shouldn't add methods to them; they should *provide* the appropriate methods themselves.

Comment: Attributes aren't objects, they are names that refer to objects. Objects have methods. If you want to be able to do `x.y.z` then `x.y` must evaluate to some object that has a `.z`